# How to mock a div length property from jquery selector in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I recently started working on jest. I do not know how to mock some jquery selectors like this :

```
  var count=$("div[id*='newDiv']").length;
  if(count>1){
  //somecode
  }
```

I am trying with returning value with >1. so my flow of count>1 should be covered.

```
  spyOn($.fn, 'length').and.returnValue(3);
```

But it is not working as expected.

Comment: Please give some more details. What problem you are facing.

Comment: Why do you need to _mock_ anything? Can you not control how many matching divs there actually are in the test environment?

Comment: In if(count>1) I have to cover some logic.